# How to optimise an SQL request containing update when?

Tags: sql

I have an SQL request that is take more than 10 seconds to load at peak hours on my server.

```
 UPDATE "events"
    SET "metas" = 732899,
        "count" = "count" + 1,
        "timestamp" = 1633450429
  WHERE "hash" = 'my_counter_453751'
```

Do you see any ways I can optimize this request?
I've tried to change my server but it doesn't change anything.

Usually, this request is almost instant, but when I have lots of users connected on my server this request takes more than 10 seconds and I don't understand why.

Any advice would help!

Comment: Which DBMS product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language used by all relational databases, not the name of a specific database product and performance tuning is highly product specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using. [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Are you using any index on that table, that helps to find the row to be updated?

Comment: For 'events' have you checked the indexes?

Answer (score 0):

> UPDATE "events" SET ... WHERE "hash" = 'my_counter_453751'

For this to work efficiently, you need an index on `hash` (if at all possible, it would be somewhat better to retrieve an integer-type primary index).

You also need as few other indexes as possible, because an index on metas, for example, too would be updated if you changed that column, and that takes time.

The fact that under load the update time goes up in that way, though, is suspicious. One of the few things that could explain this is *disk thrashing*. With many users, the events table gets evicted from memory and requires reloading. With too many indexes, and even more if there is no index on `hash` at all, this can be calamitous.

So I would also review the memory assigned to the RDBMS server, and the size of the `events` table. You could trim it down, or benefit from *sharding*. Or you could split a historical table into several tables, one per month - a poor man's sharding. This complicates retrieving information from that table, but accelerates writes.

I have also reaped huge benefits from dirty tricks such as writing these updates to a *different*, smaller table (or even to a temporary file). So, none of my hundred simultaneous clients has ever to do anything to the huge table; they all access the tiny one. Then a periodic cron job would run every minute or so, and perform all the updates together, loading the huge table in memory *only once* - and not locking or interfering in any way with the other threads, then remove the processed records from the tiny table. Maybe some such strategy can be doable for you too.

For a historic log table, you could write to a *daily* log and then pour the daily log into the large table late every night.